# passing data using post array in java-script

Tags: javascript, php

i am try to load **B.php** from **A.php** after execution in the function and pass some data using a post array from **A.php** to **B.php** within same time.

code list as follows 
**A.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert_for_the_fucntion();
     window.location.href = "B.php";
     function  alert_for_the_fucntion() {
          $.post("B.php", {action: 'test'});
     }
</script>
```

**B.php**

```
<?php 
if (array_key_exists("action", $_POST)) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'test') {
        echo 'ok';       
    }    
}    
?>
```

for testing purpose i tried to echo something in the **B.php**. but currently this is not working. have i done any mistakes?  or is there any possible method to do this.

Comment: What is `B.php.php`?

Comment: There is a typo it should be `window.location.href = "B.php";` instead of `window.location.href = "B.php.php";` and why do you redirect ?

Comment: The problem is about window.location.href, which will make you change page before doing the ajax call.

Comment: not working sir, i have done the modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does this:

1. Tells the browser to navigate to B.php (using a GET request)
2. Triggers a POST request using XMLHttpRequest

The POST request *probably* gets canceled because the browser immediately leaves the page (and the XHR request is asynchronous). If it doesn't, then the response is ignored. Either way, it has no effect.

You then see the result of the GET request (which, obviously, doesn't include `$_POST['action']`) displayed in the browser window.

---

If you want to programmatically generate a POST request and display the result as a new page then you need to **submit a form**.

Don't use `location`. Don't use `XMLHttpRequest` (or anything that wraps around it, like `$.ajax`).

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.method = "POST";
f.action = "B.php";

var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "hidden";
i.name = "action";
i.value = "test";

f.appendChild(i);
document.body.appendChild(f);
f.submit();
```

---

If you want to process the results in JavaScript then:

1. Don't navigate to a different page (remove the line using `location)
2. Add a `done` handler to the Ajax code

e.g.

```
$.post("B.php", {action: 'test'}).done(process_response);

function process_response(data) {
    document.body.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(data)
    );
}
```

Comment: hi sir thank you for the great idea 
i have tried it in this way but still not working
     <script type="text/javascript">
                            document.getElementById('jsform').submit();
                        </script>

                        <form id="jsform" action="B.php" method="POST" target="_blank"> 
            
                            <input type="hidden" value="test" name="title"/>                          
                        </form>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = alert_for_the_fucntion;
    function  alert_for_the_fucntion() {
        $.post("B.php",
               {
                 action: 'test'
               },
               function(data, status){
                  if(status=="success"){
                     alert(data);
                  }
               }
        );
    }
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        echo $_POST['action'];       
}
?>
```